# Thymeleaf template works in gradle, but not for maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, gradle, thymeleaf

So I made my first  Spring project using gradle, and I had a problem getting the database set up, so I decided to switch to maven and see what happened. Well now, my database is hooked up and works perfectly, but my thymeleaf templates aren't showing up at all! There are no errors thrown, and I simply copied and pasted the code from my packages into my new maven project, but when i go to localhost, there is no template! Everything else is still there, but without the style. I am at my wits end trying to figure out this project, can someone please point me in the right direction to solve this?

Here is my pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.stephanie</groupId>
    <artifactId>mycapec</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>mycapec</name>
    <description>Capec</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here is my applications.properties

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
# ==============================================================
# = Data Source
# ==============================================================
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login?useSSL=true
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = pass

# ==============================================================
# = Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
# ==============================================================
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# ==============================================================
# = Show or not log for each sql query
# ==============================================================
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# ==============================================================
# = Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update)
# ==============================================================
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

# ==============================================================
# = The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
# ==============================================================
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

# ==============================================================
# = Initialize the database using data.sql script
# ==============================================================
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always

#logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
```

here is what is at the top of my html files

```
<html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      layout:decorate="default">
    <head>
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: How does your directory structure look like?

Comment: i actually got it to work. I dont know if it was because i closed intellij and reopened it but its fine now. but i have another problem storing user data now :(. thank you so much for answering me.

Comment: Good to hear! I would suggest that you delete this question and open an new with the user storing problem